# Rails link_to sends data with 'get' instead of 'post'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a code in my view as

```
<% topics.each do |t| %>
<li><%= link_to "#{t.name}", {:controller => "pages", :action => "session_start", :topic_id => t.id} , :method => :post , :confirm => "Start a new QA session for '#{t.name}' ?"  %></li>
<% end %>
```

The parameter :topic_id is sent as get and appended to url, I want it to be send as a part of post body. I have tried various combinations and even read the link_to API documentation.

What am I missing on?

Comment: i think get is the default way. you can use. button_to and then do a :method => :post

Comment: I want a link and not a button.

Comment: you can do it with a link_to too sorry./

Answer (score 2):

Why not do something like:

```
<%= link_to "#{t.name}", pages_session_start_path(topic_id: t.id), method: :post, confirm: "Start a new QA session for '#{t.name}' ?" %>
```

P.S. off the top of my head I can't remember if it would be `pages_session_start_path` or `session_start_pages_path` but either way you might want to rename the URL helper in your routes.rb to something more memorable.

Make sure the route for this URL is set as `POST`

```
post "/pages/session_start", to: "pages#session_start", as: :session_start
```

Comment: Do you get any errors or it's just not POST? By the way I had an extra `}` there before by accident.

Comment: If I name the route and try the code, it is the same get request again.

Comment: Make sure your routes is set to `POST`

Comment: does not help. Still a get request.

Answer (score 2):

actually, you can do a rake routes to check the routes which you want to POST.
your routes should have something like this:

```
  resources :pages do
    member do
      post   'session_start'
    end
  end
```

then in your link, you can just do

```
<%= link_to "Hello", session_start_pages_path() %>
```

Answer (score -1):

See the [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) doc, there is a `url_options` and `html_options` hash; the option `method` must belong to the `url_options` hash, but as you have written your code, it belongs to the `html_options` hash. Try to move all your options in a single hash (in your example, you don't need the `html_options` hash) :

```
<%= link_to "#{t.name}", {:controller => "pages", :action => "session_start", :topic_id => t.id, :method => :post , :confirm => "Start a new QA session for '#{t.name}' ?" } %>
```

Comment: When I do this, everything ( method, topic and confirm) becomes a parameter for a get request.